How to remove row number of toprule of a tabular
I'd would like to complete my first paper in latex and I'm confused by ways how I could add row number for different table and restart the counter for the next table.
One of my ways is using this macro:
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

I used it for my table:
    \begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}}  L p{2.2cm} p{2cm} p{1cm}   p{1cm}  p{1.2cm}  p{1.2cm}  p{1.4cm}  p{1.2cm}  }
\caption{My caption} \label{Tab:mylable}
\small
\begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}}  L p{2.2cm} p{2cm} p{1cm} p{1cm}  p{1.2cm}  p{1.2cm}  p{1.4cm}  p{1.2cm}  }
\toprule
 \# & Dataset & Subject Area &  \# of feat. & \# of inst. & \# of classes & \# of mis. val. & \# of num. attr. & \# of cat. attr.   \\
\midrule
& Analcatdata asbestos  & Life science  & 4 & 83 & 2 & 0 & 1& 3 \\
& BreastTumor & Health & 10  & 286 & 2 & 9 & 1 & 9 \\
 \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

The row numbers are displayed the first column but how could I remove it from the toprule (first row)?
For resetting the rownum for the next table, should I use this cod?
\setcounter{rownum}{0}


Have a look at tabularray. It has build in counters for row numbers.

Can you please make a [mre]?
